# Groupby pandas with multiple categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset:

```
df
       comment                date          experience       approach    type     banana     apple   score 
fruits are healthy banana   2010-01-19     Intermediate     fitness     athlete     True      False   0.88
i love apples                2010-01-19    Expert           athlete     False      False     True     0.10
```

Is there a way to create a summary table like below?

```
  date          fruit           type           average_score_perdate_per_type
2010-01-19      banana         intermediate        0.88
2010-01-19      banana         fitness             0.88
2010-01-19      apple          Expert               0.10
2010-01-19      apple          Athlete              0.10
```

I tried:

```
df = df.groupby(['date', experience ])['score'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Whats the condition to get the words "banana" and "apples" in your experience column, when that was used for something else in your original table?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how have you created "type" column in your example summary table, but assuming (from presented data) that it is a combination of columns "experience" and "approach" you can get the same summary with following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["fruits are healthy banana","2010-01-19","Intermediate","fitness","athlete",True,False,0.88],
        ["i love apples","2010-01-19","Expert","athlete",False,False,True,0.10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["comment","date","experience","approach","type","banana","apple","score"])

fruits = ['banana', 'apple']
df['fruit'] = df[fruits].idxmax(axis=1)
df['type_2'] = df[['experience','approach']].apply(list, axis=1)

df.explode('type_2').groupby(['date','fruit','type_2']).agg({'score':'mean'}).rename(columns={'score':'avg_score'})
```

Optionally you can add `.reset_index()` at the end to get rid of pandas.MultiIndex.

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j6MQ.png)

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a easy way to add a conditional count to the code? For example, like the effect of: ```df.groupby(['date','fruit'])['type'].apply(lambda x: (x=='intermediate').sum()).reset_index(name='count')```

Comment: I think, that the easiest way to do it would be to add column `df['condition'] = df['type'] == 'intermediate'` and then suming it in `agg`.